# Sass installation issue in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I am trying to install sass for the first time. Followed the following steps:

1. Installed Ruby 2.1.5 in Windows 7 64 bit from http://rubyinstaller.org/ successfully
2. ruby -v in cmd

   ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
3. gem install sass in cmd
4. I got the following error:

   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed...
5. Fixed the above SSL error with the following line (found the solution in Stack Overflow):

   gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
6. Again, I tried running gem install sass. I got the following error.

   C:\Users\Michael>gem install sass
   D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError) from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in`parse_stream' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in`load' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in`initialize' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in`do_configuration' from D:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run' from D:/Ruby21/bin/gem:21:in`'

Can anyone help me fix this? I even tried with the 64 bit Ruby but still I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By posting an image of the error, you're making it awful hard for people with a similar problem find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by downloading an older version of Ruby as sometimes new versions are not packaged with everything. I would also try to use a compiler app such as [Koala](http://koala-app.com/). if you only want to try sass out.

Comment: that actually worked! I even thought of installing the older version but for some reason I didn't. But, it did work. Finally, I've successfully installed sass. Thanks.

Comment: i guess the newer version of Ruby (v2.1.5) has issues with SSL cert and with windows, not sure just saying.